# Debugging Drupal 6

Tags: debugging, windows-7, drupal-6

OK, I've read and attempted all of the tutorials I can find on being able to debug a locally installed Drupal 6 instance.

I'm on Windows, 32-bit.  I have access to Eclipse (obviously) as well as Visual Studio 2005/2008.

I've yet to be able to get any of the Eclipse options (XDebug, Zend, etc.) working to be able to step through code, inspect variables, etc.

I've heard good things about VS.PHP, but haven't committed to the $100 or whatever it is.

Can some of your PHP/Drupal gurus out there tell me the best, simplest, most reliable way to debug Drupal and PHP on the Windows platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use Drupal with devel module, and print to screen unobstructively using kpr(), etc.
2. Install Drupal for Firebug module (it din't work for me however)
3. Use Drupal+FirePHP (in Devel)+FirePHP (in Firebug) Firefox Addon

More details here: http://ratatosk.backpackit.com/pub/1836982-debugging-drupal

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following tutorial you can get best solution for debugging [Setting up a local Drupal multisite in a Vista/Eclipse PDT environment an debugging](http://sites.google.com/site/drupaldebugmultisite/)

Comment: For the best debug experience, install/enable xdebug on the server and use a xdebug aware IDE such Eclipse PDT or Netbeans.